# Need to replace my domain mp3 links with regex

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am moving my site's mp3 files host from my server to Amazon. However, doing a copy and replace of every link seems not to be a smart way ( it takes forever, I have more than 20,000 mp3 files hosted); Doing a "replace all" feature from notepad replaces some of my "non-mp3" links. My links look like this

http://example.com/songs/Audio_Book/God_39_s_generals_audiobook/God_39_s_generals_audiobook.mp3

and I want to reformat all of them as

http://audiocdn.example.com/songs/Audio_Book/God_39_s_generals_audiobook/God_39_s_generals_audiobook.mp3

so far the only selector I used is

```html
http\:\/\/.[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\-\_]
```

But this just selects all the links;Since I am a newbie at regex programming, I can't figure out how to reformat them. I need a smart way for reformatting these links. Thanks

Comment: Just an FYI, check out Regex Planet. They have some cool regex tools

Comment: If you need to just add `audiocdn` just replace `http://example.com/songs/` with `http://audiocdn.example.com/songs/`. No regex is required.

Comment: @Usolivier - any feedback? Please provide more details on what makes the links you need to fix unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want to insert `audiocdn.` after `http://` in your MP3 links.

If all these links just start with `http://example.com/songs/`, you do without a regex: replace `http://example.com/songs/` with `http://audiocdn.example.com/songs/` in the *Normal* mode.

If these links *must* contain `.mp3` at the end, you may consider using a regex based replacement:

**Find what**: `(http://)(example\.com/songs(?:/[^\s/]*)+\.mp3)`
**Replace with**: `$1audiocdn.$2`

**Details**:

- `(http://)`  - Group 1 matching a literal `http://` (if you add `s?` after `http` you will also match `https` links)
- `(example\.com/songs(?:/[^\s/]*)+\.mp3)` - Group 2 capturing:

  - `example\.com/songs` - literal string `example\.com/songs`
  - `(?:/[^\s/]*)+` - 1 or more sequences of `/` fillowed with 0 or more characters other than whitespace and `/`
  - `\.mp3` - literal `.mp3`

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I was looking for :).